# Invalid Token Errors when using MSBuild via Command Line but not on Visual Studio

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, build, msbuild

When I use MSBuild command through the Command Line I receive many errors in the cmd pointing to ambiguous syntax errors (approximately 300). However when I do a Build via Visual Studio 2015 I don't receive these types of issues.

Example of one of the errors:

```
Pages\BookingScreen.cs(15,38): error CS1002: ; expected [C:\BLAH\UITests\UITests\UITests.csproj]
Pages\BookingScreen.cs(15,66): error CS1519: Invalid token '(' in class, struct, or interface member declaration [C:\BLAH\UITests\UITests\UITests.csproj]
Pages\BookingScreen.cs(17,39): error CS1002: ; expected [C:\BLAH\UITests\UITests\UITests.csproj]
Pages\BookingScreen.cs(17,67): error CS1519: Invalid token '(' in class, struct, or interface member declaration [C:\BLAH\UITests\UITests\UITests.csproj]
Pages\BookingScreen.cs(23,47): error CS1002: ; expected [C:\BLAH\UITests\UITests\UITests.csproj]
```

Was wondering if anyone would know the possible differences through running "MSBuild" via command line, that may have caused an error like this to occur.

**Background info:** 
MSBuild Environment Variable points to: "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Background info: MSBuild Environment Variable points to: "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319"

Since you are using the Visual Studio 2015, you should set MSBuild Environment Variable points to the following path:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\Bin
```

Because starting with Visual Studio 2013, the 2013 version of MSBuild will ship as a part of Visual Studio instead of the .NET Framework.

You can check the Visual Studio Blog: [MSBuild is now part of Visual Studio!](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/2013/07/24/msbuild-is-now-part-of-visual-studio/) for some more details.

Hope this helps.