# How to get a MSBuild .proj to fail informatively if MSBuild tools is too early

Tags: c#, msbuild

I have a MSBuild .proj file that is executed by various people on various machines in the usual way, like  `msbuild.exe thingummy.proj`  The C# projects it compiles include .Net 4.5 features, so if you compile it with an early MSBuild that does not know about later .Nets, you'll get the "Invalid token '=' in class, struct, or interface member declaration" sorts of messages that are well documented elsewhere. (e.g. [Invalid Token Errors when using MSBuild via Command Line but not on Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51614892/invalid-token-errors-when-using-msbuild-via-command-line-but-not-on-visual-studi) )

The immediate fix is to update your MSBuild to latest and make sure you are using the version of MSBuild that you think you are.  But it would be a kindness to users if instead of getting an abstruse "Invalid token..." message (which is a bit "go figure..."), it instead said something like "MSBuild v16 or later required (yours is v4.7)" or something like that.

So what I am looking for is a `MinimumMSBuildVersionRequired` parameter or something like that to put at the top of my msbuild `thingummy.proj` file, so that at the start of the build process, MSBuild tests to see if the MSBuild that is running this script is new enough.  I've looked all over but can't find a suitable candidate for that.

Is there a such a parameter that I can set in my `.proj` MSBuild script?  Or some other workaround to give informative messages when running with inadequate MSBuild version?

Comment: You can create a target which runs on `BeforeTargets="PrepareForBuild"` and checks MSBuild version

Comment: Thanks, but my question was how do you check the MSBuild version, not where to put such a check if such a check can be done (yes, BeforeTargets would be a good place pointing at a section with any name of one's choice, or alternatively within the first target to run).

Comment: Try to use something like this `" '$(MSBuildToolsVersion)' != '' OR '$(MSBuildToolsVersion)' < '15.0' "` Pay attention that for VS2019 it returns `Current` instead of version number

Comment: Are you setting the MSBuildToolsVersion at the top of all your build scripts?

Comment: I believe that `MSBuildToolsVersion` is something you get rather than something you set.  If there is a one-liner for specifying minimum `MSBuildToolsVersion` at the top of a build script, please provide an example.

Answer (score 0):

OK, with thanks to input from @pavelanikhouski , this works:

At the top of my script, I add this:

```
<Project InitialTargets="MyInitialChecks" ...
```

'InitialTargets' is magic (must be exactly that).  'MyInitialChecks' is whatever I choose as the name of my checker target.

And then I add a checker target that looks like this:

```
<Target Name="MyInitialChecks" >
    <Error Condition="$(MSBuildToolsVersion) &lt; 15.0" 
        Text="The version of MSBuild being used for this build (v$(MSBuildToolsVersion)) is too early. v15.0 or later is required." />
</Target>
```

That does it up to and including Visual Studio 2017 and MSBuildToolsVersion v15.0.

As Pavel has pointed out, all bets are off when it comes to VS2019, because that no longer reports a MSBuildToolsVersion.  See https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/404485/vs2019-msbuildtoolsversion-is-not-a-version.html